# Imprimir json no php com títulos?

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$dadosJsonDecodificados = ("C:/pasta/arquivojson.json");
foreach($dadosJsonDecodificados->accountData $dadosBank){
   $msg = ($dadosBank->accountBalance);
}
$str = implode("\n", $msg);
echo ($str);

?>
```

Dentro do Json Exemplo :

```
    "accountData": [
    {
        "AccountName" :"Bruno",
        "accountBalance": [
                1000,
                2000,
                3000
              ]
    }
    ]
```

Resultado = String:
1000
2000
3000

e se eu quiser imprimir na tela assim :
Quantidade 1: 1000
Quantidade 2: 2000
Quantidade 3: 3000
alguem poderia me dar um exemplo ? estou pegando de um arquivo json que gera automatico !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opa bruno, então, pra fazer isso você precisa usar a função [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php). Mas esse seu código ta meio incompleto, pois pra você pegar o conteúdo desse json seria por meio de um [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) por exemplo.

```
$json = '{
   "accountData": 
      [
        {
            "AccountName" :"Bruno",
            "accountBalance": [
                1000,
                2000,
                3000
            ]
        },
        {
            "AccountName" :"Matheus",
            "accountBalance": [
                1500,
                2700,
                3090
            ]
        }
     ]
}'; // no seu caso seria o arquivo!!
```

Note que adicionei chaves no início do seu json para o exemplo

```
$obj = json_decode($json); // converte o json para um objeto

foreach($obj->accountData as $account) { // percorre cada account
    echo "AccountName: {$account->AccountName}\n";
    
    $i = 0; // contador para o balance
    foreach($account->accountBalance as $balance) { // percorre cada accountBalance
        $i++;
        echo "Quantidade {$i}: {$balance}\n";
    }
    
    echo "-------------\n";
}
```

É isso aew, espero ter ajudado!!